# How to design a database for production control?

Tags: sql, database-design

I must develop a database for inputting information of the produced volume (hourly), quality and technical issues during this production. There are 3 production lines. Each line can run through specific timespace (for example, Line A stops for lunch at 11:45 for 50 minutes, Line B and C stops at 12:30 for 60 minutes). The Line C runs only from 6 a.m. to 11 p.m., while both other Lines run all day long. The lines may have different tact-times according to the day/time, and this may be changed. Each line has an Operational Volume Objective per hour (amount of pieces that must be produced), and a Capacity Volume (that is the available time in a specific hour divided by the tact-time). The issues which stop the line must be recorded, but not hourly, since one problem can stop the line at 6:30 and only be solved at 9:14 for example. I just can't figure out how to divide all this information in different tables so that I can store this data, could someone help me please?

I've tried to input the tact-time and available time for each hour together with the actual produced volume, but the user should only input how much he produced in that hour and what were the loses, the cycle-time should come automatically from another table, which a second user can update, changing the available times and cycle-times for each line when necessary. An example on hourly info about production is shown below:

[image: Table of production result]

Comment: This kind of non-programming question might be better asked at the sister site, https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask there then :) thanks!

Comment: You might also want to try to simplify/generalize the question.